# Inner product structure for chain group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I read that an “inner product structure” can be given to the chain group $C_i(X;\mathbb{R})$, where $X$ is a simplicial complex.

However the paper (https://magnus.ece.gatech.edu/Papers/MuhammadEgerstedtMTNS06.pdf) doesn’t give any examples of such inner products. What are some examples of inner product structures that can be given?

Also I notice that notationally, if $f$ is a cochain and $c$ is a chain, we write $\langle f,c\rangle$ to mean $f(c)$. The notation resembles inner product. Is that related to the inner product structure?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That paper appears to just be referring to the unique inner product which makes the simplices of $X$ orthonormal in $C_i(X,\mathbb{R})$.  As far as I can tell, the only reason the paper mentions this inner product is that the authors have the (incorrect) belief that such an inner product is needed to define the dual chain complex.